# multiple files download in iOS and Android

Tags: javascript, android, ios, objective-c, cordova

I want to download assets (mp3/jpeg) but they are more then 200 in each case and take too much time to complete process, i am wondering if it is possible to get files in Asynchronous way? or is there a better way to get them faster in both iOS/Android?

Answer (score 0):

In iOS, as one of solutions, you can create dispatch group (to have a completion block) and `dispatch_async` your requests there, but I'm pretty sure server won't be happy with you pounding it with multiple requests simultaneously.